# Performance unpacking list of lists into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a list of lists, where the outer list is length 100k, and each inner list is length 2, with two bool entries, for example `[True, False]`. I'm trying to put each of the first entries in one column of a dataframe and each of the second entries into another. I have code that works, but it is very slow (takes about 12 seconds):

```
populate_df[["col1", "col2"]] = pd.Series(list_of_lists).apply(pd.Series)
```

Can somebody please recommend a way that performs better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
In [29]: lst = [[False,False],[True, False],[False, True]]

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['col1','col2'])

In [31]: df
Out[31]:
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1   True  False
2  False   True
```

Comment: Ah thanks, assumed it was going to create a dataframe where each internal list was another column if I did it that way. I'll accept this answer as soon as it allows.

Comment: Hi, @MaxU, how can I do that for a number of Keys. I've tried append, but to no avail.

Comment: @BFurtado, please open a new question with the corresponding small reproducible data set and your desired data set.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add columns to an existing dataframe, this will work:-

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame()
lst = [[True, False], [False, False], [True, True], [False, True]]

df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B'])], axis=1)
df.A, df.B = list(zip(*lst))

#        A      B
# 0   True  False
# 1  False  False
# 2   True   True
# 3  False   True
```